# How to keep xcode 4.0 from automatically including objective-c runtime headers in plain cpp files

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to compile a objective-c, c++, c mixed projekt for iOS. I use the llvm 2.0 compiler and set "Compile sources as" to "According to File Type". 
I disabled using prefix headers (I hope) and looked hard for wrong #import wich should be #include s.

Still I get compile errors when building the cpp files because the compiler for some reason tries to include NSObjectiveCRuntime.h.

Comment: Sounds like you still have a prefix header

Comment: How can I check this? There is no .pch file to be found in the project. Also I cleaned the build and restartet XCode.

Comment: Well you were right... when I searched my Project settings for PREFIX_HEADER I found that the entry still contained a path to UIKit.h

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the wrong entry in the build settings. Disabling "Precompile Prefix Header" does not do anything if there is still a "Prefix Header" specified. I solved my problem by:

- creating a new ProjectName_Prefix.pch
- specifying it as my targets precompiled header via "Prefix Header" in the targets Build settings
- adding the following code to it

  ```
  //
  //  Entourage_Prefix.pch
  //  Entourage
  //
  //  Created by Martin Lütke on 24.06.12.
  //  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
  //

  #include <string>
  #include <strstream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <map>

  #ifdef __OBJC__
          #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
          #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
          #import "cocos2d.h"
  #endif

  #ifdef __cplusplus
          #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
          #include <boost/function.hpp>        
  #endif
  ```

  This will allow to explicitly specify what is included via the Prefix Header in objective-c or c++.